# Using CodeIgniter libraries through static methods

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having trouble trying to call CodeIgniter methods in my static functions, just using $this doesn't work because its not in object context, the static keyword doesn't work either. This an example of the code in my core model, the $table variable is successfully defined from another model like posts.

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {

    protected static $table;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public static function find_all() {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $sql = $this->db->get(static::$table);
        return $sql->result();
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using a version of PHP that supports the `static` keyword in that context?

Comment: I am using version 5.4, so yes I think that supports it.

Comment: Does `$class = get_called_class(); $sql = $this->db->get($class::$table);` work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $this doesn't work you can get around this like this:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->db->...
```

Comment: How does this help the problem of accessing static members?

Comment: from what I understand Chris has the problem accessing core CI methods using $this e.g. $this->db
If this is the case then my suggestion resolves this issue

Answer (score 3):

The codeigniter built in loader class automatically instantiates the class. There is no support  to use classes without instantiating. You can manually include your file in the model file then you can use it. For more details check out this thread:
http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/73583/

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a refence to the static var in the class, so use:

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {

    protected static $table;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public static function find_all() {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $sql = $this->db->get(self::$table);
        return $sql->result();
    }

}
```

And, of course, $table does need to have a value!

Comment: -1: MY_Model is supposed to be extended, and `self::$table` returns `MY_Model::$table`, not the late static binding.

Comment: I do not see why he needs late static binding? Thats not the question!!

Comment: How does a static method will have `this` ?

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter doesn't generally support static methods I believe and they are really an attempt to shoehorn procedural code into object oriented code.

Anyway, I think your best bet is to either use the class without static methods, or turn your code into a "helper". A helper is just an old school function library. You would create it under the helpers folder and it can be loaded with $this->load->helper('helper_name'). You can then call the function as in normal procedural code, in other words 'find_all()'

Hope this helps.
First time contributor :)